# bucket sort analysis

Tags: algorithm

> A simple example is bucket sort. For bucket sort to work, extra
>   information must be available. The input a1, a2, . . . , an must
>   consist of only positive integers smaller than m. (Obviously
>   extensions to this are possible.) If this is the case, then the
>   algorithm is simple: Keep an array called count, of size m, which is
>   initialized to all 0s. Thus, count has m cells, or buckets, which are
>   initially empty. When ai is read, increment count[ai] by 1. After all
>   the input is read, scan the count array, printing out a representation
>   of the sorted list. This algorithm takes O(m + n);  If m is O(n), then
>   the total is O(n).
>
> Although this algorithm seems to violate the lower bound, it turns out
>   that it does not because it uses a more powerful operation than simple
>   comparisons. By incrementing the appropriate bucket, the algorithm
>   essentially performs an m-way comparison in unit time. This is similar
>   to the strategy used in extendible hashing. This is clearly not in the
>   model for which the lower bound was proven.

My question on above paragraph

1. What does author mean by "it uses a more powerful operation than simple comparisons"?
2. By incrementing the appropriate bucket, how algorithm performs an m-way comparision? By the way what is m-way comparision?
3. How above bucket sort strategy is related to extensible hashing? can any one pls give an example with extensible hashing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the `count[arr[i]]` is more 'powerful' then comparison because it is
   actually `*(count + arr[i])`. each comparison op has 2 possible
   values: true/false, while this op has much wider range of values,
   [all possible addresses!] and thus it is more 'powerful'
2. by increasing the element, the algorithm 'knows' later how many
   elements where in this 'bucket', and later: just 'spill' the
   bucket's content out. the m-way comparison the author means, 
   I assume is a 'comparison' with m possible outputs, as I explained above.
3. this is basically a hashing, you hash your elements to the range
   `[0,m]`. the importance and difference here is: two elements are
   hashed to the same number, if and only if they are identical. this
   of course can be achieved only if you hash elements with the same
   [or less] range then the image.